# Simple Blender script in VS Code causing EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, but works in Blender

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code to develop Python Blender scripts, and I've run into an odd problem.

I already had Visual Studio Code installed (1.49.3) on my Windows 10 box, so I downloaded Blender (2.90.1) and the latest stable version of Python (3.9.0). I also installed Jacques Lucke's Blender Development extension.

I was able to connect Visual Studio Code to Blender. But when I ran the following test script:

```
import bpy
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].data.vertices[0].co.x += 2.0
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(1, 0, 0))
```

Blender crashed, and I got the following error message:

```
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF6091405F3
Module  : blender.exe
Thread  : 00002968
Writing: C:\Users\aschn\AppData\Local\Temp\blender.crash.txt
The terminal process "c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.90\blender.exe '--python',
'c:\Users\aschn\.vscode\extensions\jacqueslucke.blender-development-0.0.12\pythonFiles\launch.py'"
terminated with exit code: 11.
```

However, the script works just fine when I run it directly in Blender (in its Scripting workspace).

So, I tried eliminating the line that creates a cube:

```
import bpy

bpy.data.objects["Cube"].data.vertices[0].co.x += 2.0
```

This script works fine from Visual Studio Code.

In short, from Visual Studio Code I can manipulate existing objects but I can't create a new one.

Any idea what's going on? I found a bunch of posts about the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error, but the code that was causing the problem described in these posts was far more complex.

Comment: Hello, have you looked through the issues on the project github ? https://github.com/JacquesLucke/blender_vscode/issues

Comment: I had looked for that particular error message and hadn’t seen it.

Comment: Have you authorized the application in your firewall or any other access-blocking device on your computer ?

Comment: If it’s an access issue, then I shouldn’t be able to successfully modify an object, right?  But just In case, I’ll try running VS Code in admin mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to apply a fix for a similar problem you described about the Exception Access Violation error.

The sequence to follow apparently is to go under the *Advanced* tab under Windows *System Properties* selection.  Under *Performance Options*, there is a radio button selection to *Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select:*.

Upon adding Blender 2.90, The DEP prompt displays

> You can not set DEP attributes on 64-bit executables".

I have a 64-bit Windows operating system, in which Blender 2.90 worked temporarily after adjusting the compatibility settings to Windows 8. Apparently a particular Microsoft update doesn't like the software.